# How to apply separate coord_cartesian() to "zoom in" into individual panels of a facet_grid()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Inspired by the Q [Finding the elbow/knee in a curve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41518870/3817004) I started to play around with `smooth.spline()`.

In particular, I want to visualize how the parameter `df` (degree of freedom) influences the approximation and the first and second derivative. Note that this Q is *not* about approximation but about a specific problem (or edge case) in visualisation with `ggplot2`.

### First attempt: simple `facet_grid()`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ap, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(data = dp, alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(deriv ~ df, scales = "free_y", labeller = label_both) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: facet_grid]

`dp` is a data.table containing the data points for which an approximation is sought and `ap` is a data.table with the approximated data plus the derivatives (data are given below).

For each row, `facet_grid()` with `scales = "free_y"` has choosen a scale which displays all data. Unfortunately, one panel has kind of "outliers" which make it difficult to see details in the other panels. So, I want to "zoom in".

### "Zoom in" using `coord_cartesian()`

```
ggplot(ap, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(data = dp, alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(deriv ~ df, scales = "free_y", labeller = label_both) + 
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-200, 50))
```

[image]

With the manually selected range, more details in the panels of row 3 have been made visible. But, the limit has been applied to all panels of the grid. So, in row 1 details hardly can been distinguished.

**What I'm looking for is a way to apply `coord_cartesian()` with specific parameters separately to each individual panel (or group of panels, e.g., rowwise) of the grid. For instance, is it possible to manipulate the `ggplot` object afterwards?**

### Workaround: Combine individual plots with `cowplot`

As a workaround, we can create three separate plots and combine them afterwards using the `cowplot` package:

```
g0 <- ggplot(ap[deriv == 0], aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(data = dp, alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(deriv ~ df, scales = "free_y", labeller = label_both) + 
  theme_bw()

g1 <- ggplot(ap[deriv == 1], aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(deriv ~ df, scales = "free_y", labeller = label_both) + 
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-50, 50))

g2 <- ggplot(ap[deriv == 2], aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(deriv ~ df, scales = "free_y", labeller = label_both) + 
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-200, 100))

cowplot::plot_grid(g0, g1, g2, ncol = 1, align = "v")
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this solution

- requires to write code to create three separate plots,
- duplicates strips and axes and adds whitespace which isn't available for display of the data.

### Is `facet_wrap()` an alternative?

We can use `facet_wrap()` instead of `facet_grid()`:

```
ggplot(ap, aes(x, y)) +
  # geom_point(data = dp, alpha = 0.2) + # this line causes error message
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ deriv + df, scales = "free_y", labeller = label_both, nrow = 3) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Now, the y-axes of *every* panel are scaled individually exhibiting details of some of the panels. Unfortunately, we still can't "zoom in" into the bottom right panel because using `coord_cartesian()` would affect *all* panels.

In addition, the line

```
geom_point(data = dp, alpha = 0.2)
```

strangely causes

> Error in gList(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1, just = "centre",  : 
>     only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"

I had to comment this line out, so the the data points which are to be approximated are not displayed.

### Data

```
library(data.table)
# data points
dp <- data.table(
  x = c(6.6260, 6.6234, 6.6206, 6.6008, 6.5568, 6.4953, 6.4441, 6.2186,
        6.0942, 5.8833, 5.7020, 5.4361, 5.0501, 4.7440, 4.1598, 3.9318,
        3.4479, 3.3462, 3.1080, 2.8468, 2.3365, 2.1574, 1.8990, 1.5644,
        1.3072, 1.1579, 0.95783, 0.82376, 0.67734, 0.34578, 0.27116, 0.058285),
  y = 1:32,
  deriv = 0)
# approximated data points and derivatives
ap <- rbindlist(
  lapply(seq(2, length(dp$x), length.out = 4),
         function(df) {
           rbindlist(
             lapply(0:2, 
                    function(deriv) {
                      result <- as.data.table(
                        predict(smooth.spline(dp$x, dp$y, df = df), deriv = deriv))
                      result[, c("df", "deriv") := list(df, deriv)]
                    })
           )
         })
)
```

Comment: You can remove the strip labels and axis labels for the rows/columns where they are not needed and then use the `align="hv"` argument to `plot_grid` to ensure that all the panels are the same size in the final plot. [Here's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35304121/496488) I wrote a while back that solves a different problem than yours, but that uses a similar idea for separately customizing various groups of plots that go into the final layout.

Comment: a couple of suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207419/r-how-do-i-use-coord-cartesian-on-facet-grid-with-free-ranging-axis

Comment: @eipi10 Thank you very much. I've tried it it but it adds a lot more of code (calls to `theme`) to an already voluminous code of the `cowplot` workaround. BTW: `align = "v"` works well in terms of removing white space while `align = "hv"` maintains the white space which I thought should be eliminated by replacing strip and axis labels by `element_blank()` except for the topmost strip and the bottommost axis.

Comment: @user20650 Thank you very much. I've tried to reproduce your answer in the link but apparently the numbering of grobs has changed with the new versions of `ggplot2`. In addition, it will be a variant of the `cowplot` workaround which requires to produce three different plots and combine them in an - admittedly very - clever way.

Comment: Yes, `cowplot` likes large margins between plots. In the answer I linked to, I changed the plot margins in order to reduce the amount of space between panels.

Comment: I was also [recently tripped up by the change in ggplot2's grob structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732543/seeking-workaround-for-gtable-add-grob-code-broken-by-ggplot-2-2-0). Maybe the discussion in my question and @SandyMuspratt's answer will be helpful.

Comment: @eipi10 I've added `theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,-0.15,0,-0.15), "lines"))` but the white space is still there. I believe this is because I kept the topmost strip and the bottommost axis label. When I remove all _decorations_ then `"hv"` removes all the white space but now I would have to add the strip labels and the x axis in some way...

Comment: @eipi10 Looks as it would become a deep dive into the inner workings of `ggplot`... BTW: I've added a variant using `facet_wrap()` which ran into strange `gList` error.

Comment: uwe. please see second message http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132675/uwe-facet for a quick way. I cant remember if the panel names used to describe row and column position in the facet layout: but it appears as if they dont now, so use `t` in the layout to find the relevant rows

Comment: Uwe, were you able to resolve your problem using the @user20650's code in chat?

Comment: Also, FYI, the error you're getting with `geom_point(data = dp, alpha = 0.2)` has something to do with `dp` having only one of the two faceting variables. I was able to reproduce the same error with `mtcars1 = mtcars[,c("wt","mpg","vs")]; ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(data=mtcars1) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ vs + am)`.

Comment: @eipi10 Following @user20650's suggestions in chat I'm thinking about writing a `zoom_facet_grid` function (if time permits). Alternatives to dealing with grobs could be to tweak the object returned by `ggplot_build` or to go along [Extending existing facet function](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/extending-ggplot2.html#extending-existing-facet-function)

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but the following hack just occurred to me. Would it work for your use case?

**Step 1**. Create an alternative version of the intended plot, limiting the range of y values such that `scales = "free_y"` gives a desired scale range for each facet row. Also create the intended facet plot with the full data range:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# alternate plot version with truncated data range
p.alt <- ap %>%
  group_by(deriv) %>%
  mutate(upper = quantile(y, 0.75),
         lower = quantile(y, 0.25),
         IQR.multiplier = (upper - lower) * 10) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(is.outlier = y < lower - IQR.multiplier | y > upper + IQR.multiplier) %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse(is.outlier, NA, y)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(data = dp, alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(deriv ~ df, scales = "free_y", labeller = label_both) + 
  theme_bw()

# intended plot version with full data range
p <- p.alt %+% ap
```

**Step 2**. Use `ggplot_build()` to generate plot data for both ggplot objects. Apply the panel parameters of the alt version onto the intended version:

```
p <- ggplot_build(p)
p.alt <- ggplot_build(p.alt)

p$layout$panel_params <- p.alt$layout$panel_params
rm(p.alt)
```

**Step 3**. Build the intended plot from the modified plot data, & plot the result:

```
p <- ggplot_gtable(p)

grid::grid.draw(p)
```

[image: plot]

*Note*: in this example, I truncated the data range by setting all values more than 10*IQR away from the upper / lower quartile in each facet row as NA. This can be replaced by any other logic for defining outliers.

Comment: Thank you, that's very clever!